# Annotation on MapKit pin not showing

Tags: ios, sdk, annotations, mapkit

I have placed two pins on a map, each with an annotation when clicked, however, only the annotation for `StoreLocationOne` is showing. Both pins on the map are being displayed but `StoreLocationTwo` annotation is not showing when clicked, any ideas?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [mapview setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapview setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapview setScrollEnabled:YES];

    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = 57.132053;
    region.center.longitude = -2.135592;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    [mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];

    StoreLocationOne *ann = [[StoreLocationOne alloc] init];
    ann.title = @"Heavenly Pizzas Mannofield";
    ann.subtitle = @"483a Great Western Rd, Aberdeen, AB10 6NN";
    ann.coordinate = region.center;
    [mapview addAnnotation:ann];

    MKCoordinateRegion region2 = { {0.0, 0.0 }, {0.0, 0.0 } };
    region2.center.latitude = 57.232458;
    region2.center.longitude = -2.347853;
    region2.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
    region2.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;

    StoreLocationTwo *ann2 = [[StoreLocationTwo alloc] init];
    ann2.title2 = @"Heavenly Pizzas Kintore";
    ann2.subtitle2 = @"School Road, Kintore, AB51 0UU";
    ann2.coordinate = region2.center;
    [mapview addAnnotation:ann2];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `title` and `subtitle` properties must be named exactly that.  The map view won't know to look for `title2` and `subtitle2`.

You can have multiple classes that implement `MKAnnotation` but the property names must be as per the protocol.

Additionally, if all you need are the properties `coordinate`, `title`, and `subtitle`, you could use the built-in annotation class `MKPointAnnotation` instead of creating a separate class for each coordinate.